# HTTP status code без загрузки страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript, http

Возможно ли получить с помощью `javascript'а HTTP` статус код удаленной страницы без её загрузки. Заставлять выгружать пользователя всю страницу не хочется, в особенности если по ссылке файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно проверить наличие ресурса и получить его метаданные HTTP-методом [HEAD](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#HEAD).
Например (используя [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    async: true,
    url: 'pages/example.html',
    success: function(data) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: @Shad большое спасибо, то что доктор прописал!